# access forms: forcing UCASE in a textbox

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i would like to force the textbox to immediately change the text to UCASE as soon as the user moves away from the field. is this possible?

the important thing is that this text will be used in a SQL query to update a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the after update event of the text box on the form, simply go:

```
If isnull(me.MyTextBox) = false then
   Me.MyTextBox = ucase(Me.MyTextbos)
End if
```

You can also specify a input mask on the form.

">LLLLLLLLL"

The above ">" will force all chars as you type to upper case. The number of L is a any char mask. (and, you don't need the " around the input mask)

Comment: Albert, don't you want to say something about variable length?

Answer (score 1):

Solution from Albert don't work for me.

I use this method: put form in "design view", select the control, in the property sheet, in the format tab, in the format property insert the value ">" w/o quotes.